# How to send WebSocket hybi-17 frame with php server

Tags: php, phpwebsocket

I try to implement a WebSocket Server in PHP handshaking and recieving data works well but if i try to send data to the client, Chrome 19 says
"A server must not mask any frames that it sends to the client."
But I don't mask the data.
My code looks like this:

```
function wrap($msg=""){ 

$byte1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);

if(strlen($msg) <= 125){
    $header = pack('CC', $byte1, strlen($msg));
}
elseif(strlen($msg) >= 126 && strlen($msg) <= 65535){
    $header = pack('CCn', $byte1, 126, strlen($msg));
}
else{
    $header = pack('CCN', $byte1, 126, strlen($msg));
}
$this->log($header);
return $header.$msg;
}
```

I send it to the Client using socket_write()

**EDIT:** Firefox 13 closes the connection too

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem: for some messages sent from the server there was no response in the browser, for some the error "A server must not mask any frames ..." was displayed, though I did not add any mask.
The reason was in the handshake sent.
The handshake was:

```
"HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
...
"WebSocket-Location: ws://{$host}{$resource}\r\n\r\n" . chr(0)
```

That chr(0) was the reason, after I removed it everything works.

function for encoding the messages:

```
protected function hybi10Encode($payload, $type = 'text', $masked = true) {
        $frameHead = array();
        $frame = '';
        $payloadLength = strlen($payload);

        switch ($type) {
            case 'text':
                // first byte indicates FIN, Text-Frame (10000001):
                $frameHead[0] = 129;
                break;

            case 'close':
                // first byte indicates FIN, Close Frame(10001000):
                $frameHead[0] = 136;
                break;

            case 'ping':
                // first byte indicates FIN, Ping frame (10001001):
                $frameHead[0] = 137;
                break;

            case 'pong':
                // first byte indicates FIN, Pong frame (10001010):
                $frameHead[0] = 138;
                break;
        }

        // set mask and payload length (using 1, 3 or 9 bytes)
        if ($payloadLength > 65535) {
            $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%064b', $payloadLength), 8);
            $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 255 : 127;
            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
                $frameHead[$i + 2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[$i]);
            }

            // most significant bit MUST be 0 (close connection if frame too big)
            if ($frameHead[2] > 127) {
                $this->close(1004);
                return false;
            }
        } elseif ($payloadLength > 125) {
            $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%016b', $payloadLength), 8);
            $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 254 : 126;
            $frameHead[2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[0]);
            $frameHead[3] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[1]);
        } else {
            $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? $payloadLength + 128 : $payloadLength;
        }

        // convert frame-head to string:
        foreach (array_keys($frameHead) as $i) {
            $frameHead[$i] = chr($frameHead[$i]);
        }

        if ($masked === true) {
            // generate a random mask:
            $mask = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
                $mask[$i] = chr(rand(0, 255));
            }

            $frameHead = array_merge($frameHead, $mask);
        }
        $frame = implode('', $frameHead);
        // append payload to frame:
        for ($i = 0; $i < $payloadLength; $i++) {
            $frame .= ($masked === true) ? $payload[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4] : $payload[$i];
        }

        return $frame;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code.. I used it but had to change `$masked = true` to `$masked = false`